# Regex to wrap in an anchor matched hashtags in description

Tags: javascript, regex

data model:

```
var sample = {desc: "i am #Cool #cool1234 hello world", tags:["Cool", "cool1234"]}
```

So i was able to come up with this function:

```
return sample.desc.replace(/#[a-z]+/g, "<a class=\"tags-in-details\" href=\"#/tab/myprofile-hashtags/$&\">$&</a>");
```

the problem with my function is it doesn't replace the capitals so "#Cool" will not be linked and it also doesn't include numbers so only "#cool" will be linked without the "1234".. also in my href my desired URL is

```
href"#/tab/myprofile-hashtags/Cool"
```

instead of

```
href="#/tab/myprofile-hashtags/#Cool"
```

#### Questions

1. what should be regex so Upper case letters and numbers would be linked
2. how do i remove the '#sign' in the URL (..URL/Cool instead of ..URL/#Cool)

screenshot from my app:

[image]

Comment: thanks.. sorry bout that i just patched it

Comment: Also, `sample`, being an object, does not have `.replace`. Please make sure your question is as correct as you can make it; errors at random places that have nothing to do with what you are trying to ask are distracting. In regex questions, please provide clear "before/after" examples.

Answer (score 0):

Q1) Changed `a-z` to `\w` to match with a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and _ (underscore). If you don't want to support underscore, can be replaced with `/#([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/g`

Q2) Try grouping (the parentheses in `/#([\w]+)/g`)

```
return sample.desc.replace(/#([\w]+)/g, "<a class=\"tags-in-details\" href=\"#/tab/myprofile-hashtags/$1\">$&</a>");
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eu0e31fL/2/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var sample = {desc: "i am #Cool #cool1234 hello world #notatag", tags:["Cool", "cool1234"]};
var result = sample.desc.replace(/#(?:([a-zA-Z0-9]+))/g, function() {
  var tag = RegExp.$1;
  if (sample.tags.indexOf(tag) !== -1) {
    return "<a class=\"tags-in-details\" href=\"#/tab/myprofile-hashtags/" + tag + "\">" + tag + "</a>";
  }
  return RegExp.lastMatch;
});
snippet.log(result);
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```